# Code won't enter if statement

Tags: android, okhttp

I try to make my android project enter a different activity after logging in at the log-in activity, but when my server sends me a successful response, my code won't enter my if statement that allows my program to switch my activity.I use okhttp library and so far the communication with the server goes well, but when I try to enter my if statement it just jumps out to the else. Here is the code:

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call,@NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("TAG", "success logging in!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Can't log in");
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't log in, consider registering...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

As you can see, my if statement must enter when my response from the server is "success" but even though my response is success, the program jumps to the else instead. Here is the log I get when entering valid Json data to allow logging- in: http://prntscr.com/i1ba9q

Edit: I initially gave up on comparing strings and instead used the isSuccessful() Method to see if the response is 200 or 300 ok, and eventually it worked up well. 
Thank you anyways for helping

Comment: What is `response.body().toString().length()` ?

Comment: length? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: No, I mean please change your code to log the value. (If it is != 7 then maybe you're getting some whitespace in the response)

Comment: OMG respone length is 47...

Comment: Then I think you know what to do :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
String string = response.body().toString().trim();
```

This will remove unnecessary space which might be the reason for the error!

Comment: Are there any other characters in your response than spaces? Tell the site so I can make the request!

Comment: No, visually there are only 7 characters, can't understand why it added me another 40 spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Check If your response string has extra space at start or end... That space can change string value.

Try something like this :

```
String string = response.body().toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Comment: Can I please know what this function does?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use runOnUiThread method you can use like this

```
if (string.equals("success")){
            Log.d("TAG", "success");

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Comment: Didn't help... :(